# Sorting Average Score in a file. Columns and descending

Tags: python, file, sorting, text-files, average

I have a file with 3 scores for each person. I want to use these scores, and get the average of all 3 of them. There scores are separated by tabs and in descending order.  For example:

```
jack    10    6   11
claire  3    7    3
conrad  5    4    6
```

these people would come out with an average of:

```
jack   9
conrad 5
claire 4
```

I want these to be able to print to the python shell, however not be saved to the file.

```html
with open("file.txt") as file1:
    d = {}
    for line in file1:
        column = line.split("/t")
        names = column[0]
        scores = int(column[1].strip())
```

I have made a start, but I have found myself stuck and I do not know how to continue with the coding. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use the concept of a set, or a dictionary. Both are similar: they can only contain a certain "key" once.

So if you created a dictionary that stored the contents of each score, using the 'name' as a key, you could create a data structure that looked something like this:

```
student_scores = {'dave': [9, 8, 11], 'john': [12, 7, 10], ... }
```

That data structure would be something you could analyze in a second step, easily enough, to calculate averages.

Then write a loop that goes through your `student_scores`, and averages each one. You can loop through a dictionary like this:

```
for name, list_of_scores in student_scores.items():
    # do something with name & list...
```

Hope that gives you some ideas, without just coding it for you!

Also: Remember of course that "average" is defined as the `sum` of a list of numbers, divided by the `len` of a list of numbers. Lucky for you, both of these [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html) exist in Python, and operate on lists!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary.

```
scores = {}
with open("class6Afile.txt") as file1:
    for line in file1:
        column = line.split("/t")
        names[column[0]] = column[1:]
```

Post this, you can iterate over key,value pairs as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) and find the average over each set of value against the corresponding name.

Also , you can't store names in an array the way you have done it. I'm assuming names is an array, so the correct way to do it is.

```
names.append(column[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("class6Afile.txt") as file1:
d = {}
class Person:
def __init__(self, name, average):
        self.name = name
        self.average = average
for line in file1:
    column = line.split("/t")
    name = column[0]
    average = (int(column[1].strip()) + int(column[2].strip()) + int(column[3].strip()))/3
d.append(Person(name,average))
d.sort(key=lambda x: x.average, reverse=True)
```

your desired result exist in the top of the list!

Comment: #ignore syntax errors if exist! I am not python developer :P